# Is it possible to create a customer using the WooCommerce REST API and set their locale? So the e-mail they receive to set a password is in their lang

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm building a headless WooCommerce using the WooCommerce REST API. I've followed the docs in order to create a customer: https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-a-customer

But there is no "locale" field like in the WordPress REST API for creating users: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/

I could update the created customer via the WP REST API and set their locale correctly, but at that time the customer has already received the e-mail to set their password (which will be in the default store language)...

Comment: Maybe, you could try to create the user first via WordPress Rest API (with a "customer" user role and the correct locale) and then *Update* that "customer" user via WooCommerce Rest API…